# Using the c++ Boost regex libraries in Arch Linux

Tags: c++, regex, boost, g++

I'm having trouble building a simple c++ program that tests out regex's from the boost library.  The problem that I'm having is occurring in the linking stage and I don't know enough to fix the error on my own.

In the .cpp program that uses regexes I used the following include line.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
```

I don't know enough to figure out what command I should use to build the program using g++.  I tried using the following command line (and variations of it) to build the program.

```
g++ -I/usr/include/regex -L/usr/lib -llibboost_regex main.cpp -o regex_test
```

Other information that might be relevant:

```
Operating system: Arch linux
g++ version: 4.6.2 20120120 (prerelease)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Linking should be listed after the .cpp file, if I'm not mistaken, but also, you should post the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you have installed Boost with the `boost` and `boost-libs` packages,

1. The header `<boost/regex.hpp>` should exist in `/usr/include/boost/regex.hpp`. You don't need to use any `-I` flags since `/usr/include` should be included by default.
2. You shouldn't need the `-L` flag either since `/usr/lib` should also be included by default when linking.
3. When using the `-l` flag to link with a library `libfoo.so`, the leading "lib" part should be removed.

The command line should therefore be:

```
g++ main.cpp -o regex_test -lboost_regex
```